# PHP While Loop that gets data from the database

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, push-notification

I'm building a mobile application that requires push notifications to be sent whenever a new post is added.

Here's the PHP notification script: (it should be added inside the loop so it will be used again for each result.

```
$to = (should get DEVICEID from the database).
$title = "A new request"
sendPush($to,$title,$message);
function sendPush($to,$title,$message){
  //Sends noti.
}
```

So How do I place the above code in a while loop, and get the DEVICEID from the database and place it into `$to` ?

Comment: Cool. What have you tried?

Comment: Basically you have'nt done anything

Comment: I'm not sure why they're down voting this question :/

Comment: The reason the question is getting down votes is a.) it shows no effort and b.) asks no question.

Comment: So, What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you have an mysql connection set up and that you are using mysqli.

After you have created the connection to the database, you should have a variable holding your connection:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

So right now you are able to execute a SQL statement to your database. Your SQL statement should look similarily to this:

```
$sql = "SELECT DeviceID FROM Devices";
```

Now we can execute the statement we created to the database:

```
$result = mysqli_execute($con, $sql);
```

Now we get a result object. We can use this to get a while loop:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $to = $row["DeviceID"];
    // Rest of your code, this will be executed for every DeviceID in the database.
}
```

If you are using PDO you can read more about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

But in general, the steps are the same.

Comment: And how does this check if a new post is made?

Comment: Thank you I'll give it a try.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile leave it up to me, I only need to get the data out of the loop :)

Comment: @Fala If you have any questions about how to do this that it only returns the new posts feel free to ask, I will then add it to my answer.

Comment: @Larce the while loop is working, but I'm unable to get the device id into $to, it's blank.

Comment: I think your Device ID is not named DeviceID as in my SQL Statement. Can you try to put a var_dump($row) in the loop to see what is inside the $row variable. Maybe you can also post your database definition so I can adjust my SQL statement.

Comment: @Larce none of the variables you sent are the same, I renamed everything, but the problem wasn't in your code, I was working on the wrong host. I fixed it and it's working perfectly! THANK YOU!!! not sure why people are down voting my question, lol.